# How do I read the amount of lines in a text file for my discord.js bot?

Tags: discord.js

So i'm trying to have a command that reads of the lines in the txt file.

Here's my code:

```
const path = "./commands/test.js";
const content = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8');
test = content.length
```

`msg.channel.send("The lines of code is: **" + test + "** lines")`

Whenever i do this it adds extra numbers. for example,for 2 lines it says 4, 3 is 7, and 4 is 10. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

ok so imagine a plain text file:
yourFile.txt:

```
bat
dog
cat
apple
```

now, in node.js, we run the following code:

```js
let lines = [];
require('fs').readFileSync('yourFile.txt', 'utf-8').split(/\r? 
\n/).forEach(function(line){
   lines.push(line);
});
console.log(lines[2]);
```

Output: `Cat`